# Is there a tool for converting a bitmap of a simple "shape outline" to a TikZ path?

Tags: tikz-pgf, svg

I've got the outline of a simple shape in a png. Is there a tool or technique for converting this to a TikZ outline that I can stroke with different colors and line widths etc?

Online "vectorizer" png-to-svg tools work fine for producing an svg, but I haven't had any success including the svg. My next try will be manually rewriting the svg as TikZ paths, but I wanted to ask here first if this is a solved problem.

[image]

Comment: You can use e.g. inkscape to convert the shape to svg, clean it up as needed and then convert it to tikz using `svg2tikz` (this is also avilable as plugin for inkscape, so you can do everything in one place)

Comment: Alternatively you could directly use the source of the in a tikzpicture with the `svg.path` library.

Comment: Thank you @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, I'll give it a try with the Inkscape plugin. I've tried `svg.path` earlier, and didn't manage to get it to follow the path properly.

Comment: Another option is to manually draw the tikz path. Your image could probably created with 6 points, rounded corners and in/out operators for the curvy bits. This way you would get good quality tikz code.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz That seems pretty hard. I can position the corners, but finding e.g. Bezier parameters seems like it would take a lot of trial and error while drawing the result over the original bitmap to compare. Is that what you mean? Anyway, it seems Inkscape includes a powerful bitmap tracer, so I'm sure that together with the svg2tikz plugin will work fine. Thanks for your advice!

Comment: Here a rough sketch to draw it manually: `\draw[rounded corners=0.1cm] (-0.5,2.1) to[in=45,out=225] (-1.4,-1) -- (-1,-2.2) -- (1,-2.2) -- (1.4,-1) to[in=-45,out=135] (0.5,2.1) -- cycle;` (the exact coordinates and angles need some fine tuning, but it should be enough to get you started)

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: If you would like to learn how to manually redraw an existing curve in tikz, the book https://tug.org/books/reviews/tb138reviews-kottwitz-tikz.html has a step-by-step tutorial for this.

Comment: (a bit closer approximation: `\draw[rounded corners=0.05cm,red] 
  (-0.4,2.18) to[in=35,out=205,in looseness=0.7] 
  (-1.38,-0.9) -- 
  (-1.08,-2.15) -- (1.08,-2.15) -- 
  (1.38,-0.9) to[in=-25,out=145,out looseness=0.7] 
  (0.4,2.18) -- cycle;`)